# Can't get a word out of a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've created an expression using regex in python to get the first word out of a string. However, is there any way I could find any specific word as in, `PONY` in this case. As they both are four lettered words and the latter one is capital, i think it is possible to find `PONY` using regex. I could only make an expression for the first one, though!

What i tried to find the first word:

```
import re

arg_str = "Jony is after PONY not phoney"
item = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]...+?)',arg_str)
print(item[0])
```

Comment: What do you mean? How can you describe the rule to get `pony`? [`arg_str.split()[3]`](https://ideone.com/xFGNtP)?

Comment: `(pony)` will help you find the exact word.

Comment: The regex for "specificword" is "specificword".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific word? What about the following?

```
words = re.findall(r" *\w+ *", arg_str)

for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
Jony 
is 
after 
pony 
not 
phoney
```

Comment: Thanks Sam Chats for your answer. Now I can get whichever I want using index. Btw, could you please make it a little bit easier for me by giving a oneliner explanation how you did? Forgive my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto Space followed by a * means zero or more spaces, which surround \w+, which means more than one alphanumeric characters, or a word.

Comment: Thanks Sam Chats. +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first occurrence of a word in a string, use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
arg_str = "Jony is after pony not phoney"
print(arg_str.find("pony"))
```

If you want to find the first word:

```
print(arg_str.split()[0])
```

Comment: find will find a substring: ex: `epony`

Comment: *'Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]'*